# Update Panel gets postback in IE9 and above versions

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am using update panel to avoid post back,everything is working fine in all browsers except IE.Even localhost website also working fine with IE but when i have uploaded to my site and when running as website from internet,update panel gets post back.Is there anyway to update panel  make work with IE.i have to show on modalpopup extender .Below is my code..

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="true"  EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" >
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>

    <div class="fluid">
    <div class="widget grid12">
     <div class="widget-header">
                         <div class="widget-title">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Search Criteria
                            </div>    </div>
                               <div class="widget-content pad20f">
                        <div class=" grid6">                              <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPatientId" runat="server"    placeholder="Patient Id" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> 
                             <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPPhn" runat="server" placeholder="PHN" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> 
                         <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPLName" runat="server" 
                                placeholder="Last Name" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> 
                        <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPFName" runat="server" 
                                placeholder="First Name" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> 

                 </div><div class=" grid6">
                 <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPAName" runat="server" placeholder="Alias Name" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> 
                        <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPhone" runat="server" placeholder="Home Phone" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> 

                         <div class="form-group ">

                        <div class="col-sm-12">  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPDob" runat="server" placeholder="DOB" ></asp:TextBox>  </div> </div> </div></div>
                  <div class="footer">
                          <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" class="btn btn-blue pull-right" Text="Check-Ins "  />  
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" class="btn btn-blue pull-right" 
                              Text="Search" onclick="BtnSearch_Click"  /> <asp:Button ID="Button14" runat="server" class="btn btn-blue pull-right" Text="Searching"  OnClientClick="click();"  />  
                              <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" class="btn btn-blue pull-right" Text="Clear Search"  />  </div>

    </div> </div> <div class="fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">
    <div class=" grid12">
     <div class="widget-header">
                         <div class="widget-title">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Search Results
                            </div>    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                      PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"   Font-Names="Arial" 
            AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" GridLines="None" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" />
            <columns>
                <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Select">
                    <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton id="rdbUser" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:SelectSingleRadiobutton(this.id)" />
                       <%-- <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect" CssClass="gridCB" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>--%>
                    </itemtemplate>
                </asp:templatefield>
                  </columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="LightCyan" 
                ForeColor="Black" /> 
        </asp:GridView> <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="No Records Found" Visible="false"></asp:Label></div>

                            </div>
                             </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
 <div class="fluid">
   <div class="footer">
   <div class="btns sd-btns">   
      <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" class="btn btn-blue pull-right" 
           Text="Ok" onclick="Button7_Click"  />  &nbsp;
                              <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" 
           class="btn btn-blue pull-right" Text="Cancel" onclick="Button12_Click"   /> 
            </div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you updated the browser definition file, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299(v=vs.85).aspx?

Comment: I am not aware of browser definition file,i read that document but it seems to support for single system...i am building website i cant able to say to each customer to install anything to support IE,I want to do anything in Server side..@ Lance Leonard